Why does $a\cos{\theta}$ represent rotation in the Kerr metric?
In any introductory book to GR where the Kerr metric is reviewed, they all apply transformations of the form:
$$cu' = cu + ia\cos\theta;\text{ } r' = r + ia\cos\theta$$
In the end, the result describes the gravitational field of an axisymmetrically rotating mass.
But why? I guess it has something to do with $z=r\cos\theta$, but I haven’t found any explanation on the Internet. I have read in the original paper from Boyer and Lindquist that you can presume $a$ to be the angular momentum per unit mass comparing the resulting equations to the Lense-Thirring effect ones, but I can’t see the connection between it and the transformation with $\cos\theta$.
Furthermore, I am curious to know what the transformations for $cdu$ and $r$ would be if the axis of rotation was not $z$ but rather $x$ or $y$; or even how a rotation along two axis would look like in terms of a Kerr transformation (for example, to describe a mass rotating like a pulsar, that could be described as rotating along the $z$ and $y$ axis at different speeds).

Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/57345/16685

Thanks for the comment. What you link to is rather interesting, although I don’t see the relation. The main doubt posed by this post is how are we sure $a\cos\theta$ is the right transformation to describe rotation around the $z$ axis under Janis-Newman algorithm’s transformations and what other transformations should we perform for rotation around the $x$ and/or $y$ axis.

Sorry, I wasn't implying that the linked answer answered your question. I linked it just because it has good info about the motivation underlying the Kerr rotation parameter (IMHO).

The $~du\,d\phi~$ term in the Kerr metric is crucial because it signifies the coupling between time $~u~$ and the azimuthal angle $~\phi~$. This coupling is a direct consequence of the rotating nature of the Kerr black hole, and it manifests the phenomenon known as frame dragging or the Lense-Thirring effect.
to obtain the  $~du\,d\phi~$ term in the Kerr metric you use this "complex  transformation" .
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  r' \\
  u' \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  r \\
  u \\
\end{bmatrix}+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
                   0 & i\,\cos(\theta) \\
                   i\,\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}}_{\rm Transformation}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
  a \\
  a \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where the parameter a is the angular momentum per mass $~a= \frac JM~$

When you say “azimuthal” angle, what convention are you using? Do you mean the polar $\theta$ or the azimuthal $\phi$ in the usual convention?
Why do you know that is the matrix you have to apply? And why does that entail rotation around the $z$ axis? I is not a rotation matrix, as it lacks sines of the angle.
Following the original development of Kerr ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/822807/what-is-kerr-doing-here ) it seems like he simply tried with that one, projected the angular momentum in $z$ and found it was $Ma$, thus the angular momentum per unit mass for Jz.

Is that right, or you can come up with transformations for rotation out of the box from the frame change? If so, why does the cosine of the polar angle represent rotation around $z$? What other transformation would you use for rotations around the $y$ and/or $x$ axis? The sine? Only of the polar or also of the azimuthal angle?

@Antoniou sorry the azimuth should be $~\phi~$

The complex transformation modifies the radial coordinate r and the time coordinate u
in a way that incorporates a dependence on the polar angle $~\theta~$ and the rotation parameter a.

Yeh, I see. The inclusion of the parameter is understandable. What I don’t see is why the function for the transformation is exactly the cosine of $\theta$. And what other function would we use if we wanted to model rotation along the $x$ or $y$ axis rather than the $z$.
